# Precompiling assets in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

When I run rake `assets:precompile` it takes only a few seconds to compile them, but when I run assets:precompile `RAILS_ENV = production` i get stuck on this line - `writing to active_admin-6aa404333742df4255c7a21b0c8fdc22.js`. It takes ~10 min to compile this javascript file, why is it so terribly slow and what can I do to speed up compiling?

Answer (score 0):

For faster asset precompiles, you can partially load your application by setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in `config/application.rb`, though in that case templates cannot see application objects or methods.

If you set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`, be sure to test `rake assets:clean assets:precompile` locally before deploying.